# how can I load my urls and page without the whole browser loading in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ember.js, routes, laravel-5.4

pls im looking for a new way to load my urls and pages in laravel, i want the url to change and the webpage to change but i do not want the whole browser to load, some examples are like soundcloud.com, wakanow.com, https://www.indiehackers.com/businesses,  even linkedin has the same feature, where the pages load like desktop apps and they have nice preolading animations that works with the page, i believe this will be helpful to other people too :)

Comment: Use a javascript router and an AJAX request to get the view. Good example is https://www.emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Router.html (as you tagged Ember)

Comment: As @DanWhite said, send request using ajax and change view contents on successful call

Comment: okay thanks alot guys. How can i add a preloader to it like how linkedin is when you click on the login button, or how it is on https://www.indiehackers.com/businesses when you click on the link, especially on https://www.indiehackers.com/businesses , when you click on the link the preloader loads on the top and on the lower right of the page (on desktop), im sure this will be helpful to people too. Been trying to stuffs like this, make my dream come true pls :)

Comment: how do i install router.js into my laravel project tho?? from your advices i see that it can be used in my laravel project but i dont know where or how to install it, pls help. Thanks.